# JQX Tree drag-drop checking the parent

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqwidget, jqxwidgets

I have a dynamic jqx tree (JSON) with persons as a lists of lists.  Drag-drop is currently enabled and I need to do 2 things with it:

1. Create a list of persons with an ordering change (i.e. when a child is drag-dropped amongst its siblings, then every sibling below the dragEnd will need their person.order integer updated)
2. Prevent a child from changing parents.

I know that I will need to manipulate the dragStart and dragEnd events to do this, but I'm not sure how I should be checking.

```
    $("#personTree").on('dragStart', function (event) {
        if (event.args.value) {
            // should I be setting a global var here?
        }
    });

    $("#personTree").on('dragEnd', function (event) {
        // how do I check the change in parents?
    });
```

If it helps, event.args.label is the name of the person, and event.args.value is a path to the person

e.g.  .../grand parent/parent/person

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The related information can be found here:

[link](http://www.jqwidgets.com/community/topic/darg-drop-rows-in-tree/#post-60086)